# Control clearInterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

In a dynamic counter, I want to be able to stop it and resume it. I managed to do it but the "cancel" button only works the first time; once I have restarted the counter, I can not stop it again.

I would also like to know how to improve the "resume" button code so that I do not have to repeat lines.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>setInterval</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="timer">Han pasado 0 segundos</h1>
  <button id="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
  <button id="resume-button">Resume</button>

  <script>

    const timer = document.getElementById('timer');
    let counter = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      counter++;
      if (counter == 1){
        timer.textContent = `ha pasado ${counter} segundo`;
      }else{
        timer.textContent = `han pasado ${counter} segundos`;
      }
    }, 1000)


    const cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancel-button');
    cancelButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    })

    const resumeButton = document.getElementById('resume-button');
    resumeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      setInterval(() => {
      counter++;
      if (counter == 1){
        timer.textContent = `ha pasado ${counter} segundo`;
      }else{
        timer.textContent = `han pasado ${counter} segundos`;
      }
    }, 1000)

    })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to slove it is to re assing your interval variable to the second call of `setInterval` , also dont use `const` since it read only

```js
const timer = document.getElementById('timer');
    let counter = 0;
    let interval  = setInterval(() => {
      counter++;
      if (counter == 1){
        timer.textContent = `ha pasado ${counter} segundo`;
      }else{
        timer.textContent = `han pasado ${counter} segundos`;
      }
    }, 1000)


    const cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancel-button');
    cancelButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      for(var i = 0; i<=100;i++){
      clearInterval(i)
      }
      
    })

    const resumeButton = document.getElementById('resume-button');
    resumeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      counter++;
      if (counter == 1){
        timer.textContent = `ha pasado ${counter} segundo`;
      }else{
        timer.textContent = `han pasado ${counter} segundos`;
      }
    }, 1000)

    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>setInterval</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="timer">Han pasado 0 segundos</h1>
  <button id="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
  <button id="resume-button">Resume</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[live working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dcd8xe?file=index.ts)

replace your const by let (**timer**),

```
let interval = setInterval(() => {
```

and reassign your let (**resume**)

```
interval = setInterval(() => {
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're resuming your counter you need to assign result of setInterval to your "inteval" variable, as you're using it to clear your interval.

```
const resumeButton = document.getElementById('resume-button');
resumeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
  counter++;
  if (counter == 1){
     timer.textContent = `ha pasado ${counter} segundo`;
  }else{
     timer.textContent = `han pasado ${counter} segundos`;
  }
}, 1000)
})
```

And change interval to be let instead of const